# PayPal Failure notification

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have an asp.net application

The User can purchase items and/or upgrade an existing service. I use PayPal to handle payments.

When the order is placed I put the order details into a table as a record.  I also do this so that if the User revisits my page I check a flag in that table to tell them whether payment has been received.

If not received then I display a message on my web page telling them they have requested and upgrade and that we are currently waiting for payment.

I also disable any future purchases for that User so that they do not upgrade twice (or more).

Now, it occurs to me that when the User is redirected to PayPal to make that purchase that a payment could fail or they could close the web page.

In that case then the User would not be able to ever upgrade unless they send me a support email.

What is best practice?  Wait for a time period to elapse and if no payment then allow User to try again or stick with the support email route?

If it is best to wait for a period of time what is an acceptable period of time to wait for?

I am using the post back of Form values method to imitate payment to PayPal:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do.

Each time the user is ready to leave your page and move to paypal to pay, you create

1. Clone of their order
2. A new unique ID connected with that cloned order.

So, if one order if fail, at any time the user come back is find a new set "Order"+"Unique ID". With that 2 elements can make a final payment.

You may end up with two or tree or more cloned orders, but from my experience because this is what I really do, is rare, and its safe for your customer and you.

Also please note that paypal is accept only one unique id for each order. If one ID is fail, then you must create a new one anyway.

The unique id you send to paypal go to the `invoice` parametre.
The manual for all parametres is this [pdf - PayPal Payments Standard Intergration Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_websitepaymentsstandard_integrationguide.pdf)... and there are more pdf for paypal...

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to comment.  I have already followed your thoughts in regards to 'cloning' the order. It is exactly what I am doing now.  1 thing though, what form value do you pass in for the unique ID?  I am using the custom field to specify an ID but it is always the same for that particular Client.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson The unique order id... must be different, maybe encode some how the trys, with this specify id that you say, Maybe you can have something like `AAA-BBBB-CCC-2` when the -2 is the second try.

Comment: lol manual.  What manual?  The PayPal developer's site is useless. But Is it the txn_id? I thought PayPal assigned this automatically?

Comment: That's cool :). But please do not put yourself out. I am just grateful for the answer you gave.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I have update my answer, is the `invoice`, and there is the manual with that parameter and all the rest that you can use.

Comment: Fantastic. Why did I not see that PDF?  Excellent. Thanks